# Dyanmic panel data model with interaction of lagged dependant variable in Stata

Tags: panel-data

I want to (consistently) estimate the following model:

$y_{it}=\beta_0 +\beta_1 y_{i,t-1} +\beta_2 y_{i,t-1}\times x_{it} +\beta_3 x_{i,t} +\beta_4 \Gamma_{it}+\varepsilon_{it}   $

Given I use a lagged dependent variable, I am considering to use the Arellano Bond estimator. In Stata I would run:

```
gen yXy = L.y*x 
xtabond y yXx x Gamma, vce(robust)
```

Should I be concered about the interaction?